# Ubuntu 15.10 Freezes After Random Times

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.10

My newly built computer is running Ubuntu 15.10 with an Nvidia GTX 950 using the default Nvidia binary driver version 352.63. My computer completely freezes (no sound, no screen updates) after random amounts of time after it gets into the OS, like once the system was stable for hours while another time it froze on the Ubuntu loading screen before I could even log into the thing.

I've noticed that these several lines end the syslog.1 every time the system freezes (from /var/log/syslog.1):

```
Jan 24 10:21:46 jakerPC cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.
Jan 24 10:21:47 jakerPC systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
Jan 24 10:21:47 jakerPC systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Jan 24 10:21:47 jakerPC systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Jan 24 10:21:48 jakerPC rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.12.0" x-pid="713" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
```

Hardware (Even though I'm pretty sure this will be of no use):

```
AMD FX-8320 8-Core @ Stock speeds
MSI 970 Gaming Motherboard
8GB 1600MHz Crucial Ballistix Sport RAM
EVGA SSC+ GTX 950
1TB WD Blue HDD
```

Comment: Had any luck with this?

Comment: No, not sure that my log files will help with answering either as my computer does the same thing in Arch and won't even run Debian long enough to install it. I haven't tested it at length but I noticed I got no freezes before I installed a GUI on Arch.

Comment: I just tried following https://www.linux.com/learn/cleaning-your-linux-startup-process to stop CUPS to see if that will help.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been busy. Arch doesn't have a CUPS startup process. Must be something else

Comment: Just got the same kind of freeze in the BIOS. Hardware issue. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it's been so long that I forgot I asked this question.

I tried Debian and I couldn't even install it because it froze so much. I was able to install Arch but it still crashed somewhat often. Long story short, I believe that I've fixed the freezes by properly configuring systemd and I am running stable.

EDIT: Previously I hadn't been using a bootloader, I had only used my motherboard's function of changing boot devices as I had usually only used Windows due to its stability. Information on systemd: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd

Comment: This isn't really a high-quality answer because someone who has the same problem will read it and not know what specifically to do to configure systemd on Ubuntu to solve the initial problem. Can you please add some details if you remember them?

Comment: Please add the specifics to how you solved it.

Comment: I don't think I can be more specific, I went from not using a bootloader to using one. "Configuring" may be ambiguous but I don't see how being more specific is pertinent.